# Force feign to use a specific content-type

Tags: java, spring-cloud-feign, feign

I'm using Feign to do REST calls on a remote Java interface.
Interface is defined as follow:

```
@Produces({"text/xml", "application/json"})
```

Since `JAXRSContract` simple sends `data.template().header("Accept", serverProduces);` server choose to answer with `xml` payload.

Is there any way I can force Feign to ask for `JSON payload in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

You can override headers using interceptors:

```
Feign.builder().setInterceptor(requestTemplate -> {
        Map<String, Collection<String>> map = new HashMap<>(requestTemplate.headers());
        map.put("Accept", Collections.singleton("application/json"));
        requestTemplate.headers(null);
        requestTemplate.headers(map);
});
```

The method `requestTemplate.headers(map)` looks like poorly designed, and if you pass a valid map, its values are added to the inner header map; if you pass `null` instead the inner header map is reset. That's why you need to call it twice.